# Как сделать мгновенные сообщения

Tags: ajax

У нас есть чат, который работает посредством чтения/записи в него тех самых сообщений, которые выводятся через iframe с автообновлением. Как сделать чтобы сообщения выводились без обновления, т.е. динамически, ajax. Также можно перевести его и в БД, но в любом из случаев как сделать динамическое открытие?

Для:

```
<шframe class="windows_chat" src="chatting.php" width="100%" height="450px" onload="this.scrollBottom = 9999;">..<..frame>
```

Вроде, пытался, но не получается на подгрузку автоматически: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/bdf757e8b403/create.js

Answer (score 2):

[WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) — чуть более продвинутый, чем socket.io, под-протокол WebSocket. Для простейшего чата принципиальной разницы не делает.

WAMP реализует паттерн Pub/Sub, и использует чистый tcp или любой доступный двунаправленный надёжный транспорт, поддерживающий сообщения.

[Пример чата](https://demo.crossbar.io/demo/chat/index.html#ch1) на crossbar.io

Answer (score -1):

Делайте чат на node.js + socket.io

http://socket.io/demos/chat/

Comment: @webphp, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.